# Lambda for JavaFX Task

Tags: java, javafx

The compiler gives me this error "Target Type of lambda expression must be an interface" for this code:

```
Task<Iterable<Showing>> task = () -> sDAO.listFiltered();
```

`listFiltered()`'s return type is `Iterable<Showing>`.
How can I use the `Task` interface with lambda?

Answer (score 13):

`Task` is an abstract class, not an interface, and so it cannot be directly created with a lambda expression.

You would typically just use an inner class to subclass `Task`:

```
Task<Iterable<Showing>> task = new Task<Iterable<Showing>>() {
    @Override
    public Iterable<Showing> call throws Exception {
        return sDAO.listFiltered();
    }
});
```

If you want the functionality of creating a `Task` with a lambda expression, you could create a reusable utility method to do that for you. Since the abstract method `call` that you need to implement in `Task` has the same signature as the interface method in `Callable`, you could do the following:

```
public class Tasks {

    public static <T> Task<T> create(Callable<T> callable) {
        return new Task<T>() {
            @Override
            public T call() throws Exception {
                return callable.call();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Since `Callable` is a `FunctionalInterface` (i.e. an interface with a single abstract method), it can be created with a lambda expression, so you could do

```
Task<Iterable<Showing>> task = Tasks.create(() -> sDAO.listFiltered());
```

There is an [explanation](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-March/008441.html) of why lambdas are not allowed to be used to create (effectively) subclasses of abstract classes with a single abstract method on the OpenJDK mailing list.

Comment: Only problem now is that I can't do it with methods thats return void type. It says "void cannot be converted to Void"

Comment: Neither the `call` method in `Task` or in `Callable` can be `void`. Instead, declare them to return a `Void` and return `null` (the only legal value for a `Void` reference type).