# Java FX Platform.runLater(() -> equivalent for long running Tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, lambda

I learned that in JavaFX the equivalent of

```java
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
   dosomething();
 }
});
```

might simply be

```java
Platform.runLater(() ->{ dosomething()};
```

for a             long running task I learned that you need to wrap things with a Task like:

```java
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
  @Override
  public Void call() {
    dosomething();
  }
};
new Thread(task).start();
```

Now it would be great to be able to have a similar lambda shortcut like

```
TaskLaunch.start(() -> dosomething());
```

I found

- [JAVA FX - Lambda for Task interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089593/java-fx-lambda-for-task-interface)
- [Swing timer alternative for JavaFX and the thread management difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487345/swing-timer-alternative-for-javafx-and-the-thread-management-difference/22490928#22490928)
- [Thread with Lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416784/thread-with-lambda-expression)

discussing some of the issues around this and tried:

```java
package com.bitplan.task.util;    
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

/**
 * this is a utility task to launch tasks with lambda expressions
 * 
 * @author wf
 *
 */
public class TaskLaunch {
  /**
   * 
   * @param callable
   * @return the new task
   */
  public static <T> Task<T> task(Callable<T> callable) {
    Task<T> task = new Task<T>() {
      @Override
      public T call() throws Exception {
        return callable.call();
      }
    };
    return task;
  }
}
```

with a JUnit test:

```java
  Integer counter=0;
  boolean running=false;
  public Integer increment() {
    running=true;
    while (running) {
      counter++;
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }
    }
    return counter;
  }
  /**
   * @throws Exception 
   */
  @Test
  public void testTaskLaunch() throws Exception {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089593/java-fx-lambda-for-task-interface
    Task<Integer> task=TaskLaunch.task(() -> increment());
    try {
      Thread.sleep(20);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      //
    }
    running=false;
    assertTrue(task.get()>10);
  }
```

Which doesn't quite do what I'd like to see yet. The issue seems to be that 
the lambda expression runs in the same Thread and the

```
new Thread(task).start();
```

part needs to be integrated.

**What is needed to get (at least close to)  the short one liner mentioned above?**

Is a

```
TaskLaunch.start(() -> dosomething());
```

feasible?

based on @Damianos proposal https://stackoverflow.com/a/44817217/1497139

I tried:

```
package com.bitplan.task;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;

/**
 * this is a utility task to launch tasks with lambda expressions
 * 
 * @author wf
 *
 */
public class TaskLaunch<T> {

  Thread thread;
  Task<T> task;
  Callable<T> callable;
  Throwable throwable;
  Class<T> clazz;

  public Thread getThread() {
    return thread;
  }

  public void setThread(Thread thread) {
    this.thread = thread;
  }

  public Task<T> getTask() {
    return task;
  }

  public void setTask(Task<T> task) {
    this.task = task;
  }

  public Callable<T> getCallable() {
    return callable;
  }

  public void setCallable(Callable<T> callable) {
    this.callable = callable;
  }

  public Throwable getThrowable() {
    return throwable;
  }

  public void setThrowable(Throwable throwable) {
    this.throwable = throwable;
  }

  public Class<T> getClazz() {
    return clazz;
  }

  public void setClazz(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  /**
   * construct me from a callable
   * 
   * @param callable
   */
  public TaskLaunch(Callable<T> callable, Class<T> clazz) {
    this.callable = callable;
    this.task = task(callable);
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param callable
   * @return the new task
   */
  public static <T> Task<T> task(Callable<T> callable) {
    Task<T> task = new Task<T>() {
      @Override
      public T call() throws Exception {
        return callable.call();
      }
    };
    return task;
  }

  /**
   * start
   */
  public void start() {
    thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.start();
  }

  /**
   * start the given callable
   * @param callable
   * @param clazz - the return Type class
   * @return - the launch result
   */
  @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
  public static TaskLaunch start(Callable<?> callable, Class<?> clazz) {
    TaskLaunch<?> launch = new TaskLaunch(callable, clazz);
    launch.start();
    return launch;
  }

}
```

and changed the test to:

```
  /**
   * @throws Exception 
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Test
  public void testTaskLaunch() throws Exception {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089593/java-fx-lambda-for-task-interface
    TaskLaunch<Integer> launch = TaskLaunch.start(()->increment(),Integer.class);
    try {
      Thread.sleep(20);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      //
    }
    running=false;
    assertTrue(launch.getTask().get()>10);
  }
```

This is close to what i am up to but I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:268)
at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:83)
at javafx.concurrent.Task.runLater(Task.java:1225)
at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1417)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

At least TaskLaunch now wraps:

1. Thread
2. task
3. callable
4. a potential Exception/Throwable
5. the runtime class of the result of the Task

Some of these 5 items might be redundant and available from the standard java concepts. I think at least its handy to have quick access to these after running things from a one liner.

Hope this gets to a working state and thanks for the help!

Comment: Platform.runLater is used to update the GUI from a non GUI thread , once the GUI thread is free it takes up the responsiblity to update the GUI where as Tasks are used  for Data intensive tasks that are not related to GUI and you want them running on the background so that it dosnt freeze the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `new Thread(() -> dosomething()).start()` should do the trick

Comment: Thanx for the hint. The one line is now working - see the work around in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a traditional [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378).

A `Task` is much more than just a background thread, hence for this you can use regular threads. It's the beauty of the properties!

The real benefit of using `Task` is that all state changes and progress updates can safely be observed and bound to a live scene, while doing all the background work on a different thread. It's the work of the class to do the heavy-lifting and call `Platform.runLater`.

The reason you need a **subclass** and not a runnable is so you can call its protected `updateXxx()` methods without worrying for threading issues.

With this said, you'll have no benefit if this would've been a single line code. For this use simple threads.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My motivation is "syntactic sugar". Its just nice if it can be expressed in a short one liner and the nitty gritty details can be hidden. I think its also a good use of information hiding and it would make the decision long running/short running task easier to implement if the code change is minor.

Comment: You can easily use @Damiano's solution. Otherwise, YOU CAN'T. As said, this trying to solve problem X and inventing problem Y.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this will cause you to lose the ability to update stuff back to the UI thread natively supported by `Task` class. On the other hand, I do agree this can be useful if you want to do something in background in "do-and-forget" style.

The problem is just like what you said - you didn't add `new Thead()` and `Thread.start()` in. Do this:

```
public static void runInBackground(Runnable runnable) {
    Task<Void> task = new Task<>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            runnable.run();
            return null;
        }
    };
    new Thead(task).start();
}

runInBackground(() -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().hashCode()));
```

Note that your `Task` can no longer be non-void, because it cannot return anything back now. Your lambda needs to be able to reference the `Task` object to return a result asynchronously - that is never going to be possible using lambda.

Comment: I am happy with the wrapping approach as outlined. I can do fire & may be forget.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is now in the question based on Damianos hint.

The workaround for the exception I found is

```
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(() -> {
});
```

But seems a little bit hacky ...